# MVC Controller JsonResult error Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent, while return

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Have this function in a Controller:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> getTipoPerfil(int id)
    {
        PerfilesCalificacion pc = await db.PerfilesCalificaciones.FindAsync(id);
        int ret = -1;
        if (pc!=null)
        {

            switch (pc.Tipo)
            {
                case TipoCalificacion.NotaGlobal:
                    ret = 0;
                    break;
                case TipoCalificacion.PerfilCalificacion:
                    ret = 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    ret = -1; ;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult { Data = ret };
    }
```

In the return line above I'm getting the error.
I searched a lot but I cannot find the solution.

This function it is called by a JS function. This is part of the HTML (cshtml):

```
.
.
.
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ApiTdEx.PerfilCalificacionId, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LstPerfiles, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "MuestraPerfil()" })
.
.
.
<script>
function MuestraPerfil() {

    var idperfil = document.getElementById("ApiTdEx_PerfilCalificacionId").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("getTipoPerfil", "MenuProfesor")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: $("#ApiTdEx_PerfilCalificacionId").val() },
        success: function (tipo) {
            alert(tipo);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

I have some code in global.asax that maybe have some relation:

```
 private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;
        context.Response.BufferOutput = true;
        string culture = null;
        if (context.Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Length > 0)
        {
            culture = Request.UserLanguages[0];
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code in isolation seems fine. Do you have any other underlying code which is setting some response headers? Do you have any other endpoints which are successfully returning JSON?

Comment: Hi, I added some code from global.asax.
And all other JSON are returning seccesfully.

Comment: I worked arround this problem with other type an diferent of solution... but I want know why this is happening

Comment: francisco Mc Manus, there is a special place in hell reserved for people who say they figured out how to fix a problem on StackOverflow and then don't share what that solution is :)

Comment: Oooh Michael I did not fix the problem... maybe my english isn't very good. What I meant to say is I did not use this code.